How to fix the "Required field" error when submitting a form with images to the Django Rest Framework
I created a serializer to create a description and a photo:
class ImageFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageFile
        fields = ["image"]


class DescriptionFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_file = ImageFileSerializer(many=True)
    file_filename = serializers.CharField()
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.id")

    class Meta:
        model = DescriptionFile
        fields = ["pk", 'file_filename', 'user_id', 'title', 'description', 'line_video', 'tags',
                  'image_file', "time_create"]
        read_only_fields = ('time_create',)

By sending a request to this views:
class DescriptionFileView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DescriptionFile.objects.all().annotate(
        file_filename=F("file__filename")
    ).select_related("user", 'file').prefetch_related("tags", "image_file")
    serializer_class = DescriptionFileSerializer
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthorOrStaff]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["time_create", "user__id", "tags__name"]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, JSONParser)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

I get an error:
{
"image_file": [
"Required field."
]
}

I use this HTML form to send a request:
<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/description/file/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br><br>
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea><br><br>
    <label for="line_video">Line Video:</label>
    <input type="text" id="line_video" name="line_video"><br><br>
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input type="number" id="tags" name="tags"><br><br>
    <label for="file">File:</label>
    <input type="text" id="file" name="file_filename"><br><br>
    <label for="image_file">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_file.image"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

How can I fix the error?
python==3.11.9
django==4.2.11
drf==3.15.1

How can I test views for the post method?
I searched for a question, found +- similar questions, but they did not help.
I solved the problem like this:
class DescriptionFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_file = ImageFileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    uploaded_images = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=False, use_url=False),
        write_only=True
    )
        fields = [fields...,
                  'image_file', "time_create", "uploaded_images"]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data.pop("uploaded_images", None)
        tags = validated_data.pop("tags", None)
        file_name = validated_data.pop("file_filename", None)
        file = File.objects.get(filename=file_name)
        des = DescriptionFile(file=file, **validated_data)
        des.save()
        des.tags.set(tags)
        for image in images_data:
            ImageFile.objects.create(description_file=des, image=image)
        return des


You need to double check that html form is actually sends image_file  field. You can do it in your browser by accessing network page where you can see all the requests/responses you send/received to/from backend. There might be an issue with naming.
Edit:
Seems that problem is with line
<input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_file.image"><br><br>

It should be like this
<input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_file"><br><br>


is, such data is accepted: title: uuu
description: g
line_video: https://u.com/u
tags: 1
file_filename: f
image_file.image: (binary)

If what you provided is what the front sends to backend seems the problem is with the name image_file.image. Change it to just  image_file and it should work.

I've tried this before, the error is the same

Can you provide the actual json which front sends to back. You can omit the values which are sent, but the keys are important to identify the issue.

Also I noticed, that image_file requires a list because ImageFileSerializer(many=True).
